# Does "argument list too long" restriction apply to shell builtins?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line-arguments

I have browsed through many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands) on Stack Overflow as well as a few related communities regarding the `argument list too long` topic and I don't seem to clearly figure if the length restriction applies to shell builtins or not.

Let's say I want to pass a very long string to a command through standard input:

```
string="a very long list of words ..."
```

Can I say:

```
# not using double quotes around $string is deliberate
printf '%s\n' $string | cmd ...
```

or

```
cmd <<< $string
```

Or even pipe it to `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\n' $string | xargs cmd ...
```

Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: Related document: [ARG_MAX, maximum length of arguments for a new process](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)

Comment: Related: [Bash command line and input limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19354870/6862601).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In bash, the OS-enforced limitation on command-line length which causes the error `argument list too long` is not applied to shell builtins.

This error is triggered when the `execve()` syscall returns the error code `E2BIG`. There is no `execve()` call involved when invoking a builtin, so the error cannot take place.

Thus, both of your proposed operations are safe: `cmd <<< "$string"` writes `$string` to a temporary file, which does not require that it be passed as an argv element (or an environment variable, which is stored in the same pool of reserved space); and `printf '%s\n' "$cmd"` takes place internal to the shell unless the shell's configuration has been modified, as with `enable -n printf`, to use an external `printf` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't seem to figure if the length restriction applies to shell builtins or not.

Probably not, but you should check the source code of your particular version of `bash` (since it is free software). However, there obviously is some -hopefully larger- limitation (in particular because some `malloc` done inside `bash`  could fail), but then you'll get another error message or behavior.

AFAIK, the argument list too long error is given by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) failing with `E2BIG`, and builtin functions of bash don't `fork` then `execve` (like command invoking external programs do).

In practice, `E2BIG` might appear with a few hundred thousands bytes (the exact limit depends upon the kernel and system) but I guess that builtins could be used on several dozens of megabytes (on today's desktops). But YMMV (since you could use `ulimit` to have your shell doing some [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)...). I won't recommend handling gigabytes of data thru shell builtins.

BTW, [xargs(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) can be helpful, and you could even raise the limit (for `E2BIG`) by recompiling your kernel (and also thru some other ways, in recent kernels). A few years ago that was a strong motivation for me to recompile kernels.

Comment: Everything here is true -- but if a malloc failed (f/e), that would be an error other than `argument list too long`.

Comment: Of course. Did I wrote something which makes you think that?

Comment: I took it from the context, since this question is explicitly asking about "argument list too long".