# "Argument list too long" while slurping JSON files

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have thousands of JSON files, and I want to merge them into a single one. I'm using the command below to do this.

```
jq -s . -- *.json > result.json
```

But I am getting argument list too long error, probably because of the number of files I'm trying to merge. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Related: [Does “argument list too long” restriction apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47443380/6862601).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Built-in commands are [immune](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47443380/6862601) to that limitation, and `printf` is one of them. In conjunction with `xargs`, it would help a lot to achieve this.

```
printf '%s\0' *.json | xargs -0 cat -- | jq -s .
```